# Spark - How to create a sparse matrix from item ratings

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sparse-matrix, recommendation-engine

My question is equivalent to R-related post [Create Sparse Matrix from a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207850/create-sparse-matrix-from-a-data-frame), except that I would like to perform the same thing on **Spark** (preferably in **Scala**).

Sample of data in the data.txt file from which the sparse matrix is being created:

```
UserID MovieID  Rating
2      1       1
3      2       1
4      2       1
6      2       1
7      2       1
```

So in the end the columns are the movie IDs and the rows are the user IDs

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

I've actually started by doing a `map` RDD transformation on the `data.txt` file (without the headers) to convert values into Integer, but then ... I could not find a function for sparse matrix creation.

```
val data = sc.textFile("/data/data.txt")
val ratings = data.map(_.split(',') match { case Array(user, item, rate) =>
    Rating(user.toInt, item.toInt, rate.toInt)
  })
...?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest way is to map `Ratings` to `MatrixEntries` an create `CoordinateMatrix`:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{CoordinateMatrix, MatrixEntry}

val mat = new CoordinateMatrix(ratings.map {
    case Rating(user, movie, rating) => MatrixEntry(user, movie, rating)
})
```

`CoordinateMatrix` can be further converted to `BlockMatrix`, `IndexedRowMatrix`, `RowMatrix` using `toBlockMatrix`, `toIndexedRowMatrix`, `toRowMatrix` respectively.

Comment: I am doing something similar with Python: `mat = CoordinateMatrix(groupped_df.rdd.map(lambda r: MatrixEntry(r.userId, r.itemId, r.rating)))`. But this does not account for duplicate items. So, my unique users are 4300, my unique items are 2800, and in the end, I get a Coordinate Matrix that is 18300 by 90200. So, is this a normal behavior, and how can I remove duplicates?

Comment: @JimVer I'd say it depends on the business logic. If you have duplicate ratings for the same user, it probably makes sense to summarize (average, median, take the most recent one) your data first.