# Distributed cross correlation matrix computation

Tags: algorithm, apache-spark, distributed-computing, distributed, cross-correlation

How can I calculate pearson cross correlation matrix of large (>10TB) data set, possibly in distributed manner ? Any efficient distributed algorithm suggestion will be appreciated.

update:
I read the implementation of apache spark mlib correlation

```
Pearson Computaation:
/home/d066537/codespark/spark/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/stat/correlation/Correlation.scala
Covariance Computation:
/home/d066537/codespark/spark/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/RowMatrix.scala
```

but for me it looks like all the computation is happening at one node and it is not distributed in real sense.

Please put some light in here. I also tried executing it on a 3 node spark cluster and below are the screenshot:

[image: Entire Computation timeline]
[image: One the task details]

As you can see from 2nd image that data is pulled up at one node and then computation is being done.Am i right in here ?

Answer (score 5):

To start with, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112657/spark-correlation-matrix-from-file-of-ratings?answertab=votes#tab-top) to see if things are going right.   You may then refer to any of these implementations: MPI/OpenMP: [Agomezl](https://github.com/agomezl/pearson-correlation-mpi) or [Meismyles](https://github.com/meismyles/pearson-cc), MapReduce: [Vangjee](https://vangjee.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/computing-pearson-correlation-using-hadoops-mapreduce-mr-paradigm/) or [Seawolf42](https://github.com/seawolf42/mapreduce-correlation). It'd also be interesting to read [this](http://www.analyticbridge.com/profiles/blogs/what-mapreduce-can-t-do) before you proceed. On a different note, [James's thesis](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f02f/0df4922351375aa304de7de296393cdf7224.pdf) provides some pointers if you're interested in computing the correlations that are robust to outliers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the James's Thesis. It would be great if you can answer this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42428424/how-to-calculate-mean-of-distributed-data

Comment: James thesis talks about Maronna and Quadrant covariance computation but I could not able to understand these 2 algorithm, Do you know any link where these 2 algorithms are explained.

Answer (score 0):

Each local data sets can converted into stdv and covariances.
Also stdv and covariance and sum make correlation.

This is working example
https://github.com/jeesim2/distributed-correlation