# Create sparse matrix from movie ratings

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Basicaly i am trying to do the same thing as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32402475/spark-how-to-create-a-sparse-matrix-from-item-ratings) but in python.

What i tried so far:

I read the file and save it in a dataframe. Then i use this code `A = np.array(df)` to create a numpy array. My problem is that when i try to convert it to a sparse using the code `s = sparse.csr_matrix(A)` i get this error `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('bool') according to the rule 'safe'`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: I posted the code i am using except the code i use to load the file that is common and has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: The problem in your `df`, it is likely to contain strings, which drives to dtype='O'. 

Also, hard luck you were able to save ratings in pandas, because this is matrix of huge size and pandas.DataFrame is dense

Comment: Thats why i want to use a sparse matrix. And yes it contains strings. Do you suggest an other approach?

Comment: Show us the `A` shape, and a sample of the values.  From the error we already know `dtype=object`.  Have you tried the panada version of sparse?  Also tell us what you want to do with this sparse matrix.