# Lists into Matrix

Tags: r, excel, matrix

I have some data in excel sheet which looks like the following:

```
User    | Query
u1      | q3   
u2      | q7    
u2      | q7
u3      | q1
u3      | q10
u3      | q8
u4      | q9
u4      | q2
```

Now I want to cover this data into matrix like:

```
   q1 q2 q3 q7 q8 q9 q10
u1 0  0  1  0  0  0   0
u2 0  0  0  2  0  0   0
u3 1  0  0  0  1  0   1
u4 0  1  0  0  0  1   0
```

I don't know what is the name of this sort of matrix but I want to make graph from this matrix. So is there any way to get the matrix from the list mentioned above using any either "R" or "excel?

Comment: Consider the top answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207850/create-sparse-matrix-from-a-data-frame) to make a sparse matrix object (perhaps that is what you want if there are many zeroes),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a two-way contingency table.

You first need to read your data into R from excel sheet as a data frame. You may use `read.csv` or `read.table`, but as you did not provide a sample of your sheet, I can't produce exact code for this.

Now, suppose the data frame is `d`, then we can do

```
xtabs(~ User + Query, d)

#     Query
#User   q1  q10  q2  q3  q7  q8  q9
#  u1    0    0   0   1   0   0   0
#  u2    0    0   0   0   2   0   0
#  u3    1    1   0   0   0   1   0
#  u4    0    0   1   0   0   0   1
```

or

```
table(d[[1]], d[[2]])

#       q1  q10  q2  q3  q7  q8  q9
#  u1    0    0   0   1   0   0   0
#  u2    0    0   0   0   2   0   0
#  u3    1    1   0   0   0   1   0
#  u4    0    0   1   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: Thank You Zheyuan Li. your answer help perfectly. appriciate you effort